# AJAX Search returns "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" on non-admin user

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search

I have this demo website that I'm making:
https://theme.artware.gr/

The problem I am facing is on the search functionality. You can click on the right/top side search to see the issue. When I am logged-in as admin, the search works fine, but when I view the page as a guest I get the error: "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page".

This is my code so far:

```
// AJAX Search (no WooCommerce)
if ( !class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {

  function simple_search_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'simple_search', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/search.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('simple_search', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce') ));
  }

  // Create shortcode
  function simple_search(){
    simple_search_scripts(); ?>
    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()" placeholder="<?php _e('Αναζήτηση...'); ?>" />
    <div id="datafetch"></div>
    <?php
  }
  add_shortcode('simple_search', 'simple_search');

  // Fetch data
  function simple_search_callback(){
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 's' => esc_attr( $_GET['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      $myquery = esc_attr( $_GET['keyword'] );
      $a = $myquery;
      $search = get_the_title();
      if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) { ?>
        <div class="result-sin">
          <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' ); ?>
          <div class="result-sin-img">
            <?php if ($image) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image[2]; ?>" /></a>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="result-sin-tit"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></div>
          <div class="result-sin-txt"><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
        </div>
      <?php }
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    die();
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_simple_search', 'simple_search_callback' );
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_simple_search', 'simple_search_callback' );

}
```

And the search.js:

```
function fetch(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      action: 'simple_search',
      keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val(),
      nonce: myAjax.nonce
    },
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
    }
  });
}
```

And on the header, I simply call a shortcode `[simple_search]` . Everything post I read on SO said that the `wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION` was missing. But I already have that.

**UPDATE**
I tried using method GET, that didn't work. I also used: `wp_localize_script('simple_search', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce') ));` to better enqueue the admin-ajax.php, that didn't work either.

Comment: Sadly that didnt work. I think I have to use `wp_localize_script` somehow.

Comment: I tried with `wp_localize_script` and still I get the same error. I can't understand where I should look to fix that problem.

Comment: I already did that and i still get "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" error. I updated the code above with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere In my theme I had `require_once('file.php')` that had the line below:

`if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) ); }`

When I removed this, the problem was fixed.